# React web app product version is different from the one running on the local host

Tags: reactjs, progressive-web-apps

I have been developing a PWA using React js. Recently I am trying to publish the final real version as it is nearly finished being developed. I published it using `npm run build` that produces the optimized version. When I try to run the app from the real server it is slightly different in styles and some functionalities in comparison with the version which is running on the localhost. I have cleaned the npm cache and tried organizing all my styles into one clean file -App.css-. This is bothering me for 3 days now and I've searched for it but nothing worked. Any suggestions that might actually work? I'm really stressed as this issue is not even clear enough to deal with. Thank you

Comment: is this only on the server? what about running `npm run build` and serving it locally?

Comment: @azium Thank you for your suggestion. I have not tried this before, I just ran the build version and I saw no difference locally! But still, I don't know why the one running on the server is different.

Comment: try to open the index.html from the build folder before upload it to server